# How to represent very large and a very small values in a plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I need to plot 3 values in a histogram. One of them is a very large value compared to the other ones. When I try to plot them, because of the large one other two values do not show up in the graph. Is there any approach to illustrate them in a graph other than histogram in Python? Is there any scaling trick to solve this problem?

The code given below is the one I tried. I used python library numpy and matplotlib to plot the graph.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

height = [0.422602, 0.000011, 0.000453]
bars = ('2X2', '4X4', '8X8')
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))

plt.bar(y_pos, height, color = (0.572549,0.2862,0.0,1))
plt.xlabel('Matrix Dimensions')
plt.ylabel('Fidelity for Matrices with Sparsity 1')
plt.xticks(y_pos, bars)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The output is the picture included above. This picture does not depict the values of other two columns. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.yscale('log')`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html) or [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale('log')`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale.html)

  - `plt.yscale('log')` or `ax.set_yscale('log')`
  - `'symlog'` if there are negative values.
- Many parameters can be set in [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set.html)

  - `ax.set(yscale='log')`
- This solution is relevant for `matplotlib`, `seaborn` axes level plots, and `pandas` plots.

### Imports and Data

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

height = [0.422602, 0.000011, 0.000453]
bars = ('2X2', '4X4', '8X8')
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))
```

### Example 1

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 3))

ax1.bar(y_pos, height, color = (0.572549,0.2862,0.0,1))
ax1.set(xlabel='Matrix Dimensions', ylabel='Fidelity for Matrices with Sparsity 1', title='y without log scale')
ax1.set_xticks(y_pos)
ax1.set_xticklabels(bars)

ax2.bar(y_pos, height, color = (0.572549,0.2862,0.0,1))

# set yscale; can also use plt.yscale('log') or plt.yscale('symlog')
ax2.set(yscale='log', xlabel='Matrix Dimensions', ylabel='Fidelity for Matrices with Sparsity 1', title='y with log scale')
ax2.set_xticks(y_pos)
ax2.set_xticklabels(bars)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Example 2

```py
plt.bar(y_pos, height, color = (0.572549,0.2862,0.0,1))
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Matrix Dimensions')
plt.ylabel('Fidelity for Matrices with Sparsity 1')
plt.xticks(y_pos, bars)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of the bar itself, as differences of the number are just too big to be displayed.

In this case usually logarithmic axes are used. This means you do not have a linear axis, but a logaritmic one. See the documentation here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/scales/log_bar.html